# Update_all using object attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm interested if it is possible to use objects attribute as value in `update_all` method.

Let's say we have relation `Article` and it has attributes `part1` and `part2`. Now I want to update attribute `part1` of all objects in relation `Article` with value of `part2`.

```
Article.update_all(part1: current_object.part2)
```

Where `current_object` i just used for representation of currently updated object.

I know that I can do something like that

```
Article.find_each { |article| article.update(part1: article.part2) }
```

But I wanted to know if this is achievable with `update_all` method.

Comment: Sure it seems possible, why not just try it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below code will do it. But why are you doing this? -))

```
Article.update_all("part1 = part2")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just need this in migration, where I need to reassign values from attribute I remove to the newly added one to prevent data lost.